# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'character.txt'

Tags: python

I seem to be getting this odd error, `Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'character.txt'`.  How would I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding:utf-8
import re
import os.path
def gci(rootdir):
for parent,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in filenames:
        text=os.path.join(parent,filename)
        split_to_character(text)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Set a propper title and place the full exception code in the question. Ask an actual question. What does `split_to_character()` do? How do you call that function?